# Is Docker images in CI/CD only useful for multi host?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

We are two people developing a single host app in Docker, where we would like to cut some testing time and use CI/CD.

Many articles are about using a paid service for running the tests and building the Docker images, and then deploy the images.

In a a multi host environment I can see the advantages of deploying images, but what about single host?

Is deploying images just an extra layer of complexity in single host cases?

**Update**

What we are doing now is pushing the changes to Git and then manually test the app, and if it is fine, then merge to master and login to the production server and do `git pull && docker-compose build`.

When I talk about deploying Docker images in the question, deploying on production would almost just be `docker pull`. The key difference is the docker image in not built on the production server, but somewhere else.

It is this I am asking about. Are there any advantages of building the images somewhere else when it only get deployed on a single host/machine/server/node ?

Comment: It can be useful on one host too. A docker container provides an additional layer of isolation (it's leightweight, contains only what you need + you don't "pollute" the host), it's easy to distribute between machines if you want to move your application in a later stage, you can track successive versions of a container + easily perform rollbacks, ... There will probably be more

Comment: It seems really unclear here what you mean by "host".

Comment: Also - how are you supposed to run container without its image?

Comment: Good points. I have now updated the OPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering to already updated question:

*Are there any advantages of building the images somewhere else <...>?*

**Yes, there are some.**

1. You **don't have to keep build tools on production server** updated; in fact, you don't need them at all. This reduces a chance of possible version mismatch between dev/QA/prod environments, reduces chances of some 0-day vulnerabilities found on your server, etc. Generally speaking, the less additional software lives on a production server, the better.
2. With an already built container you are open to many options immediately:

   - **Dynamical scalability**. Once you found you have a flood of users, all you have to do is raise new VM and pull container there. Or even start another container on the same host and balance them.
   - **Hotfix deployment**. It's possible that under heavy load some bug arises. And the production server may just be out of resources when you try to simultaneously serve tons of users *and* build new bugfix container.
   - **Disaster recovery**. In case your production host is suddenly dead, all you have to do is to run docker container anywhere else. You may suffer from an unoptimized environment in this case, but at least you won't have to write explanation e-mail to users about N-hours downtime.

I can keep up, but to summarize: it all depends on how much users you have, how do you plan to grow through time, how much resources you have and how much of them are needed to build, how tolerant you're to downtime, etc. Of course, you can build container at the prod server and upload it to docker repo and live happily in case this is a small non-critical internal portal. But if you're some kind of social network startup, you'd better start to separate environments and create various plans on scalability and recovery. And having app built on a separate server is a good part of such plan.